# UIButton Outlet Set title Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, iboutlet

I have set up an outlet as follows using a storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet var completeButton: UIButton!



self.completeButton.titleLabel = UIFont (name: standardFont, size: 22.0)
```

give the error cannot assign to the result of this expression.

Simple task but can't seem to get round this in swift.

Comment: `UIButton`'s `titleLabel` property is a `UILabel`, not a `UIFont`. I think you mean `self.completeButton.titleLable.font = UIFont(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing out the `font` property and titleLabel needs to be unwrapped. Try the following:

```
self.completeButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22.0)
```

Comment: Thanks Stupid mistake, been up too long :)

Answer (score 0):

@Melvin Wijenayaka: For your example, the UIFont constructor contains two parameters 
this will also work for you

```
self.completeButton!.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 22.0)
```

Note: You missed out the property font in your code.